# replacescene stops background music in my game cocos2d ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am writing a code for a game in cocos2d. I has 5 CCScenes.I am trying to implement background music in my game. I am playing a same file in all the CCScenes. and I have implemented all the volume related tasks in a singleton class called as controller.
so my problem is whenever I navigate from one scene to another scene, the background music starts but as soon as new page is loaded it stops. 
I want the music to be played continuously Can anyone help me?
here is my code that plays my sound file-

```
 [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:@"main_game_bg.mp3"];
 [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setBackgroundMusicVolume: [[Controller sharedMySingleton] getBgVolume]];
```

I have written these two lines in my main menu class. these play the sound on main menu screen as well as when i navigate to screen 1st. but as soon as i go to next screen i.e. screen2, it restarts music and after screen 2 is loaded, it stops the music. and same happens with next screens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:@"blues.mp3" loop:YES];
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"alien-sfx.caf"];
```

You forgot to mention loop in the first line